# Use Ansible to start Docker containers on docker-machine?

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a Rails app I am deploying in Docker containers. I want to do development from the Docker container so it will behave consistently between environments.

I have an Ansible playbook that starts up the Docker containers on the remote server, and that's working fine. I thought I'd use the same Ansible tasks to start the containers and link them together on my Mac.

However, when I run the playbook against my local instance, I get errors like:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "`docker-py` doesn't seem to be installed, but is required for the Ansible Docker module."}
```

It seems like the problem is that Ansible is doing a local ssh to the Mac, but I need it to connect to the docker-machine.

How do I use Ansible to run tasks on Docker containers running on my Mac?

Comment: Did you try to install `docker-py`? It complains about that.

Comment: Yes, and when the playbook runs, it installs docker-py and reports OK, and in the very next step it complains about not having docker-py. But I think it's because Ansible is trying to run these on my Mac and not on the docker-machine on my Mac. Maybe.

Comment: If your suspicion is correct then try to install `docker-py` on your Mac and see what happens then.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had already done so: I installed it at the command line and I also wrote an Ansible task to install it as part of the playbook and got the result I described above--it installs and then reports that it can't find docker-py.

Comment: @DavidHam I am having the same issue. What did you end up doing to resolve this?

Comment: @NathanC I just posted an answer below, hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was indeed that Ansible is trying to ssh into my local machine. When you run Docker on a Mac, it creates a virtual machine, and when you run commands like `docker ps` in a terminal, it is running against the Docker Engine running on that virtual machine.

I ended up following the advice in this article: [Using Vagrant and Docker Machine Together.](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/08/04/using-vagrant-docker-machine-together/) I created a new VM with vagrant, based on the ubuntu/trusty64 image, and then I enabled it for use with Docker using `docker create`. I then added the IP of this VM to my Ansible inventory file, like so:

```
192.168.99.101 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/virtualbox/private_key
```

It's a little awkward because there's no way to make this new VM the default one that Docker Toolbox uses, but otherwise it's a nice way to control the host os of your virtual machine.

I'm trying out docker-compose again, as I think it might be better for local development, but it is nice to be able to run the same playbook to deploy to any environment.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the ansible you need to make sure where it is running

```
- hosts: HOSTS_TO_RUN_FOLLOWING_TASKS
  tasks:
    - name: NAME_OF_TASK
      shell: SHELL_CMD
```

When you want to run on different hosts in the same ansible you just need to write this again:

```
- hosts: NEW_HOST_TO_RUN_TASKS
  tasks:
    - name: NAME_OF_TASK
      shell: SHELL_CMD
```

If you put "localhost" in the "hosts:" then it will run on local host.
If you want to run on a specific host then run the command `/etc/ansible/hosts --refresh-cache` and use the tags in the result.

For instance if the result is

```
"tag_Name_Production":
[
   "124.125.125.121", 
   "124.125.125.122", 
   "124.125.125.123"
]
```

and you want to run the command on all these just use:

```
- hosts: tag_Name_Production
  tasks:
    - name: NAME_OF_TASK
      shell: SHELL_CMD
```